# Is the following question on paper-writing etiquette appropriate for MO?

Tags: discussion, on-topic, specific-question

I'm wondering if it would be appropriate to ask a soft question on MO regarding mathematical etiquette. In more detail, I'm writing a paper that cites a well-known paper in my field, but I've been informed that there are concerns regarding the validity of parts of that paper. I'm curious about how to tactfully handle referring to the results in that paper, so I would like to ask an MO question about it. Would such a question be appropriate?

Comment: [academia.se] might be more suitable.

Comment: Probably you'd be better off discussing this in private, so that you can actually talk about the specific paper.

Comment: I would like to read the answers to such a question. I don't think it matters that it is also on topic on Academia: as I understand it, it is part of the Stackexchange "model" that a question may be on topic on several sites. Moreover, I am mostly interested in opinions from mathematicians, not academics in other fields.

Comment: @DanPetersen you know, you could read it on academia.SE, too ;-) And all the mathematicians that want to say something on it could answer it there, too. And to have some other opinions in addition, at least might not hurt. Actually, it could be interesting as in other fields I think it is more frequent one faces a situation where there is some disagreement regarding the validity of published things. Finally, it is well-known that at least some do *not* consider such questions as on-topic on MO.

Comment: This is not answering your question at all. But, I think this rather successful question on MO is quite "relevant" to your case: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/31337/how-do-i-fix-someones-published-error.

Comment: Ah - that question addresses my situation very well, thanks! The only difference is that I'm not the one who found (or completely understands) the error, but there's some good advice there for me to think about.